# Code coverage not reflecting in SonarQube UI

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to establish a static code analysis using SonarQube. Created a project  in SonarQube UI. Ran the sonarscanner within Jenkins pipeline.

The pipeline ran successfully and the report was published to SonarQube but it is not showing the code coverage as expected :

[image]

It shows that the tests were found but still shows the coverage to be 0%.

I have used jacoco plugin in my pom.xml :

```
   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.8.6</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

I am running jacoco:prepare-agent and jacoco:report inside my pipeline. Even tried to run mvn clean install prior to running the jacoco goals but no use.

Also check the xml file generated under target/surefire-reports which shows the tests were run :

---

### Test set: in.javahome.myweb.controller.CalculatorTest

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec

SonarQube version : 7.9.4
Jenkins version : 2.259

Any pointers as where the issue might be would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This typically means that you haven't properly integrated the jacoco plugin with the surefire plugin.  The only way that you can get code coverage results is if surefire runs in a way that will generate code coverage data.  They will not integrate together by default.

The important part of both plugins is the following:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jacoco.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                    is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

And this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
```

Comment: Was able to generate code coverage using surefire plugin. Thanks @David M. Karr